# broadcast receiver is receiving even after un-register in onDestroy()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have my Activity in such a way that

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{


onCreate(bundleInstnace){
  super.onCreate(bundleInstnace);
//IntentFilter intentFilter with some actions
 registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}


onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
 try{
 unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)
  }catch(Exception e){}
}



final Receiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

      //functionality based on actions
      }

   }

 }
```

even though i am unregistering myReceiver in onDestroy() , even after call to onDestroy, still the broadcast receiver is able to receive. I tried with registering in onStart() and unregister in onStop() but still the same. Can you help me exactly where i am missing.the occurrence of issue is random..

Comment: Add logger in onReceive of Broadcastreceiver and in onDestroy to see if the Broadcastreceiver is called after onDestroy. After that we can try to find the cause.

Comment: @Ranjith : Yes Ranjith, the log in onReceive() is getting called after onDestroy,                                                    00:05:58.630 - OnDestroy() enter
00:05:58.630 - OnDestroy() exit
00:05:58.700 - from OnReceive()

Comment: @sureshn : Have you declared your receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml` with an `<intent-filter>` section?

Comment: @Squonk, no, i am creating intent filter and adding actions to it and registering in onCreate() lifecycle method.

Comment: @sureshn : In that case it suggests the call to `unregisterReceiver` is failing. You have an empty catch block.... `catch(Exception e){}`. You should never use empty catch blocks as they can hide errors. At the very least put `e.printStackTrace();` in there and check logcat for any errors logged.

Comment: @Squonk, I have kept e.printStackTrace() inside catch block, but no exception was reported.  Is there any way to check the status of  a broadcast receiver, I mean whether it is un-registered or not.

Comment: @sureshn : I don't know of a way to check if a receiver is registered or not although the 'system' obviously has to keep track somehow and there may be an OS service which could tell you. The only thing you're doing differently to when I create/register receivers is you are declaring a final receiver and initialising it 'inline'. I create private inner classes for most of my receivers and create a `new` instance before registering and set the instance reference to `null` after unregistering.

Comment: @Squonk, I also tried by removing final in declaration of receiver and made the reference as null (myReceiver = null), after call to unregisterReceiver(myReceiver ) . but still the issue is still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Call `super.onDestroy();` after unregistering receiver. (Though it is not recommended to use `onDestroy` because it is not guaranteed to be called. use `onStop` instead.)

```
onDestroy(){

     try{
     unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)
      }catch(Exception e){}

    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: @Abhisek, I tried in the both the ways, but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

You should register receiver in **onResume** and unregister in **onPause**:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Log here or ignore
    }
}
```